# Comma-separated list of acronyms

Tags: lists, enumitem, acronyms

I am trying to create a comma-separated list of acronyms with the packages `acro` and `enumitem`. The following example used to work, but with the newest (2.8) version of `acro`, it produces several errors (`undefined control sequence`). The output is nevertheless correct.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{commalist}{itemize*}{3}
\setlist[commalist]{itemjoin={{, }}, afterlabel= \unskip{{ }}}

\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcroListStyle{commalist}{list}{list=commalist}
\acsetup{list-style = {commalist}}
\DeclareAcronym{vwu}{short = {vwu}, long = {a test}}
\DeclareAcronym{xyz}{short = {xyz}, long = {another test}}

\begin{document}
\ac{vwu}
\ac{xyz}

\printacronyms
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can reproduce the error messages on my updated MikTeX. The messages are about internal commands of the `acro` package, so you should definitely contact the maintainer about this even if you get a work-around here. https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues

Comment: Thanks, I've created an issue: https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/issues/108/errors-with-enumitem-and-comma-separated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments.